# For Loop Function in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, dataframe

I have been struggling to figure out why I am not returning the correct values to my data frame from my function. I want to loop through a vector of my data frame and create a new column by a calculation within the vector's elements. Here's what I have:

```
# x will be the data frame's vector
y <- function(x){
 new <- c()
 for (i in x){
  new <- c(new, x[i] - x[i+1])
 }
 return (new)
}
```

So here I want to create a new vector that returns the next element subtracted from current element. Now, when I apply it to my data frame

```
df$new <- lapply(df$I, y)
```

I get all NAs. I know I'm missing something completely obvious...

Also, how would I execute the function that resets itself if df$ID changes so I am not subtracting elements from two different df$IDs? For example, my data frame will have

```
ID  I   Order   new
1001    5   1   1
1001    6   2   -2
1001    4   3   -2
1001    2   4   NA
1005    2   1   6
1005    8   2   0
1005    8   3   -2
1005    6   4   NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't this `for (i in x)` be `for (i in 1:length(x))`?

Comment: IMHO your problem is `for (i in x)`; `i` will loop through each element `x` but you are using `i` as an index. Try, e.g. `for (i in seq(along=x))`. Also you should think about preallocation of your vector `new`. BTW `diff` seems to be the function you are looking for.

Comment: I suspect that you do not understand that dataframes are lists and x[i] would be an entire column, and that you are therefore subtracting adjacent columns. You are also going to create a classic programming error when "i" is at the end of the list elements and you try to get "i+1".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid the loop and use `diff`.  Everything is vectorized here so it's easy.

```
df$new <- c(diff(df$I), NA)
```

But I don't understand your example result.  Why are some `0` values changed to `NA` and some are not? And shouldn't `8-2` be `6` and not `-6`?  I think that needs to be clarified.

If the `0` values need to be changed to `NA`, just do the following after the above code.

```
df$new[df$new == 0] <- NA
```

A one-liner of the complete process, that returns the new data frame, can be

```
within(df, { new <- c(diff(I), NA); new[new == 0] <- NA })
```

**Update :** With respect to your comments below, my updated answer follows.

```
> M <- do.call(rbind, Map(function(x) { x$z <- c(diff(x$I), NA); x }, 
                          split(dat, dat$ID)))
> rownames(M) <- NULL
> M
    ID I Order  z
1 1001 5     1  1
2 1001 6     2 -2
3 1001 4     3 -2
4 1001 2     4 NA
5 1005 2     1  6
6 1005 8     2  0
7 1005 8     3 -2
8 1005 6     4 NA
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your solution. You are correct, the -6 should be 6. The reason for the NA values is because the ID changes. Since I'm taking the next element and subtracting it from the element before it, I can't calculate a difference of the last occurrence of df$I of df$ID. Let me know if that clears it up for you!

Comment: Anyway I can edit your code to account for the change in df$ID? The output shouldn't subtract elements from different df$ID.

Comment: @herkyonparade - the fact that the output shouldn't subtract elements from different df$ID is very important and is not clear at all in your question.  Can you update the question with this information please?

Comment: Sorry, I did mention it but it may not have been clear enough. Hopefully this helps.

Comment: @herkyonparade - Please see my updated answer. Hope that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a loop, you would be better off using a vector version of the math. The exact indices will depend on what you want to do with the last value... (Note this line is not placed into your `for` loop, but just gives the result.)

```
df$new = c(df$I[-1],NA) - df$I
```

Here you will be subtracting the original `df$I` from a shifted version that omits the first value `[-1]` and appends a `NA` at the end.

EDIT per comments: If you don't want to subtract across `df$ID`, you can blank out that subset of cells after subtraction:

```
 df$new[df$ID != c(df$ID[-1],NA)] = NA
```

Comment: Thanks, I just threw in a "-" sign to return the results I wanted because it was subtracting the original from the next element. Anyway I can edit your code to account for the change in df$ID? The output shouldn't subtract elements from different df$IDs. I appreciate your response!

Comment: You can also swap the order of elements `df$I=c(...)` to subtract second from first. I had it that way originally but changed it to match your results. So you want NAs for the last element in each list...? I've added a statement to do that, although there a many ways to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` library makes it very easy to do things separately for each level of a grouping variable, in your case `ID`. We can use `diff` as @Richard Scriven recommends, and use `dplyr::mutate` to add a new column.

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(new2 = c(diff(I), NA))
Source: local data frame [8 x 5]
Groups: ID

    ID I Order new new2
1 1001 5     1   1    1
2 1001 6     2  -2   -2
3 1001 4     3  -2   -2
4 1001 2     4  NA   NA
5 1005 2     1   6    6
6 1005 8     2   0    0
7 1005 8     3  -2   -2
8 1005 6     4  NA   NA
```